# Find the Array Difference in Multi dimensional array when key is same

Tags: php, arrays

I want to find the difference between two Multi dimensional array when key value is same.
I have tried every thing and so many Stackoverflow solution but I'm not able to do it.

**Array 1 (DbData) :-**

```
$ajaxData = array("phase-5[]" =>
    array(
        '1' => "Admin Phase 1 Task 1",
        '2' => "Admin Phase 1 Task 2" 
    ),"phase-6[]" =>
    array(
        '1' => "Admin Phase 2 Task 1", 
        '2' => "Admin Phase 2 Task 2",
        '3' => "Admin Phase 2 Task 3" 
    ),"phase-7[]" =>
    array( 
        '1' => "Admin Phase 3 Task 1", 
        '2' => "Admin Phase 3 Task 2",
        '3' => "Admin Phase 3 Task 3"
    )
);
```

**Array 2 (AjaxData) :-**

```
$dbData = array("phase-5[]" =>
    array(
        '0' => "Admin Phase 1 Task 1", 
        '1' => "Admin Phase 1 Task 2"
    ),"phase-6[]" =>
    array(
        '0' => "Admin Phase 2 Task 1",
        '1' => "Admin Phase 2 Task 2"
    ),"phase-7[]" =>
    array(
        '0' => "Admin Phase 3 Task 1",
        '1' => "Admin Phase 3 Task 2" 
    )
);
```

**PHP code :-**

```
$ajaxDataList = array();
foreach ($ajaxData as $key => $value) {
    print_r($key);
    foreach ($value as $data) {
        $ajaxDataList[] = $data;
    }
}

$dbDataList = array();
foreach ($dbData as $key => $value) {
    print_r($key);
    foreach ($value as $data) {
        $dbDataList[] = $data;
    }
}
var_dump(array_diff($ajaxDataList, $dbDataList));
```

**O/P from code :-**

```
 array (size=2)
  4 => string 'Admin Phase 2 Task 3' (length=20)
  7 => string 'Admin Phase 3 Task 3' (length=20)
```

I'm able to find the difference between two array but I'm not able to find diffrence with key. **I just need to add key here. But I'm not able to do it.**

I need a structure like this,

```
array (size=2)
  'phase-6[]' => string 'Admin Phase 2 Task 3' (length=20)
  'phase-7[]' => string 'Admin Phase 3 Task 3' (length=20)
```

Comment: Write one foreach loop for Array 1 then write nested loop to trace keys-value pair for Array 2. Try mapping array1 keys with array 2 with the help of nested loop, you can write output to new array once you noticed difference in looping structure

Comment: i think array_diff_assoc ( ) is helpful for you
it compares also key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Easy solution with small changes***

1.You need to add keys with some unique character (I used `/`) to all values of each array inside your 2 `foreach()` code

2.After getting difference iterate over this array and explode with a unique character (I used `/`) and then use first part as key and second part as value and assign them to your final result array

Do like below:-

```
$ajaxDataList = array();
foreach ($ajaxData as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $data) {
        $ajaxDataList[] = $key.'/'.$data; //add key with each value
    }
}

$dbDataList = array();
foreach ($dbData as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $data) {
        $dbDataList[] = $key.'/'.$data; // add key with each value
    }
}
$semi_final_array = array_diff($ajaxDataList, $dbDataList);

$final_array = [];

foreach($semi_final_array as $arr){ // iterate over difference array
   $exploded = explode('/',$arr); //explode data
   $final_array[$exploded[0]] = $exploded[1]; // use exploded array as key value pair
}

print_r($final_array);
```

Output:-https://eval.in/984265

Answer (score 1):

Write a recursive function.

**Note:** Your sub array keys must be same, in first array, sub array keys start from 1 and but in second array, it start from 0. If you can make it same this function would work

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php#73972

```
function array_diff_assoc_recursive($array1, $array2)
{
    foreach($array1 as $key => $value)
    {
        if(is_array($value))
        {
              if(!isset($array2[$key]))
              {
                  $difference[$key] = $value;
              }
              elseif(!is_array($array2[$key]))
              {
                  $difference[$key] = $value;
              }
              else
              {
                  $new_diff = array_diff_assoc_recursive($value, $array2[$key]);
                  if($new_diff != FALSE)
                  {
                        $difference[$key] = $new_diff;
                  }
              }
          }
          elseif(!isset($array2[$key]) || $array2[$key] != $value)
          {
              $difference[$key] = $value;
          }
    }
    return !isset($difference) ? 0 : $difference;
} 

var_dump( array_diff_assoc_recursive(  $ajaxData, $dbData) );
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/Irj1m)

Comment: Thank you for your time. Your solution is also working. But exact Output is achieved by @Alive to Die.  I'm upvoting you because your answer is also working .

Comment: @WebRence and that means mine does not work? Just asking what is wrong.

Comment: @Andreas. I want to get output like this `array (size=2)
  'phase-6[]' => string 'Admin Phase 2 Task 3' (length=20)
  'phase-7[]' => string 'Admin Phase 3 Task 3' (length=20)`. But in your answer output just return the diffrence which I already get.

Comment: @WebRence That a very unclear way to say you need the key. It took me several minutes to figure out what you meant. Updated the code in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop both arrays and compare against each other.
Otherwise if one subarray exists in one array but not the other the difference won't be noted.

```
//Loop once first array and compare against the other
Foreach($ajaxData as $key => $arr){
    If(isset($dbData[$key])){
        $ret[] = array_diff($arr, $dbData[$key]);
    }else{
        // If subarray only exists in one array add it to return array
        $ret[] = $arr;
    }
}
// Then the other way around
Foreach($dbData as $key => $arr){
    If(isset($ajaxData[$key])){
        If(!isset($ret[$key])) $ret[$key] = array_diff($arr, $ajaxData[$key]);
    }else{
        // If subarray only exists in one array add it to return array
        $ret[] = $arr;
    }
}

// echo found diff's.
Foreach($ret as $key => $val){
    If(is_array($val)){
        Foreach($val as $v){
            Echo $key ." " . $v . "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/ZVc00